You can’t open the application “Runner” because this application is not supported on this Mac
Hello I am trying to run my flutter project on iOS simulator. I'm using Vscode and it keeps crashing with this pop-up error from xcode:
Runner quit unexpectedly.
Click Reopen to open the application again.
Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to
Apple.

And when I click Reopen I get the following:
You can’t open the application “Runner” because this application is not supported on this Mac.
I do not understand what is going on here. Why isn't "Runner" supported on my Mac? I do have Xcode installed. Furthermore how do I resolve this issue with "Runner"?
BTW this is some of the error report, I replaced my Path with path to core simulator here and Identifier with <my bundle id>. The error report is excessively long, but this is the gist of it:
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 219EEFA2-2F1C-40A2-A282-65B8CC5B42BD
CrashReporter Key:   04969868-FD54-972B-ACE2-051A54D4CD91
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             Runner [38143]
Path:                path to core simulator here
Identifier:         <my bundle id>
Version:             1.0.0 (1)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [1433]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.1591F679-92E8-4914-B779-E3E56F97120D [1155]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1422]

Date/Time:           2024-09-14 12:40:01.0866 -0400
Launch Time:         2024-09-14 12:39:53.2309 -0400
OS Version:          macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Runner [38143]

Triggered by Thread:  4

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x112875521 __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x10f0947e8 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                         0x11287502f -[NSException init] + 0
3   Runner                                 0x104314c65 GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedCorrectly + 214
4   Runner                                 0x104314e23 0x10426b000 + 695843
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x11266d3ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x11266e6d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x112671793 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1587
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x112680e26 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x112681888 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4ceb43 _pthread_wqthread + 262
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdacf start_wqthread + 15

Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd702dc ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x10625124c ???
2   QuartzCore                             0x10ecd3d3a CA::Transaction::commit() + 728
3   UIKitCore                              0x13c50d227 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 34
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1127d1daa __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1127d155d __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 391
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1127cbe3c __CFRunLoopRun + 940
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1127cb6ad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
8   GraphicsServices                       0x122dd408f GSEventRunModal + 137
9   UIKitCore                              0x13c4edad1 -[UIApplication _run] + 972
10  UIKitCore                              0x13c4f2551 UIApplicationMain + 123
11  UIKitCore                              0x13b56c563 0x13b4c7000 + 677219
12  Runner                                 0x10426e3db static UIApplicationDelegate.main() + 123
13  Runner                                 0x10426e357 static AppDelegate.$main() + 39
14  Runner                                 0x10426e448 main + 24 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
15  dyld_sim                               0x10ce023e0 start_sim + 10
16  dyld                                   0x204915345 start + 1909

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd70414 ???

Thread 2::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x104ae191c ???
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x11266ee96 _dlock_wait + 46
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x11266eced _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 40
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x11267e4c7 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 356
5   libdispatch.dylib                      0x11267e025 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 196
6   UIKitCore                              0x13c2d4170 __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_2 + 108
7   CoreFoundation                         0x11287c15c __invoking___ + 140
8   CoreFoundation                         0x112879483 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 302
9   Foundation                             0x1163d48e2 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 17
10  Foundation                             0x1163d44a2 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 642
11  Foundation                             0x1163d9017 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 205
12  libxpc.dylib                           0x1159d7ad0 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36

...

16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x112675f59 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 424
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x112676e17 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 406
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1126829a8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 276
19  libdispatch.dylib                      0x112681f72 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 552
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4ceb84 _pthread_wqthread + 327
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdacf start_wqthread + 15

Thread 3:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd8e94c ???

Thread 4 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x106285664 ???
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d1ebd pthread_kill + 262
3   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x115ac4d1c abort + 133
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x11c4facf2 abort_message + 241
5   libc++abi.dylib                        0x11c4ed4fa demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
6   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x10f072fba _objc_terminate() + 96
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x11c4fa14b std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 6
...

Thread 5:: com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1046377ac ???
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b70878 mach_msg2_internal + 84
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b69178 mach_msg_overwrite + 653
4   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b6237d mach_msg + 19
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1127d1863 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143

...

runMode:beforeDate:] + 213
9   Foundation                             0x1162d8f58 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 72
10  UIKitCore                              0x13c5cb85a -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 518
11  Foundation                             0x116303515 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d218b _pthread_start + 99
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdae3 thread_start + 15

Thread 6:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd8e94c ???

Thread 7::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd702dc ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1046c2c70 ???
2   CoreServices                           0x112eb9b55 _LSDServiceGetXPCConnection + 76
3   CoreServices                           0x112eba11c _LSDServiceGetXPCProxyForServiceClass + 21
4   CoreServices                           0x112eba2ef +[_LSDService synchronousXPCProxyWithErrorHandler:] + 63
5   CoreServices                           0x112e18d41 __56-[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForAdvertising]_block_invoke + 139
6   CoreServices                           0x112ec0906 _LSRetryForConnectionInterrupted + 48
7   CoreServices                           0x112e18c59 -[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForAdvertising] + 118
8   AdSupport                              0x10cf42c58 -[ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier] + 224
9   Runner                                 0x1042ba60a 0x10426b000 + 325130
10  Runner                                 0x1043156a9 0x10426b000 + 698025
11  libdispatch.dylib                      0x11266d3ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x11266e6d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 8

...

Thread 8:
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd8e94c ???

Thread 9:: io.flutter.1.ui
0   ???                                    0x10c5637d0 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1054fb604 ???
2   ???                                    0x166c075bc ???
3   ???                                    0x166c07305 ???
4   ???                                    0x166c07007 ???
5   ???                                    0x166c06d14 ???
6   ???                                    0x166c04b75 ???
7   ???                                    0x1642834d6 ???
8   Flutter                                0x11fc1cbcd dart::DartEntry::InvokeFunction(dart::Function const&, dart::Array const&, dart::Array const&) + 365 (dart_entry.cc:125)
9   Flutter                                0x11fc8e37c dart::Class::Invoke(dart::String const&, dart::Array const&, dart::Array const&, bool, bool) const + 716 (object.cc:4745)
10  Flutter                                0x11ff597d3 Dart_Invoke + 755 (dart_api_impl.cc:4595)
11  Flutter                                0x11fb7b92c flutter::InvokeDartPluginRegistrantIfAvailable(_Dart_Handle*) + 92 (dart_plugin_registrant.cc:38)
12  Flutter                                0x11fb7ba1b flutter::FindAndInvokeDartPluginRegistrant() + 209 (dart_plugin_registrant.cc:66)
13  Flutter                                0x11f600cea flutter::DartIsolate::RunFromLibrary(std::_fl::optional<std::_fl::basic_string<char, std::_fl::char_traits<char>, std::_fl::allocator<char>>>, std::_fl::optional<std::_fl::basic_string<char, std::_fl::char_traits<char>, std::_fl::allocator<char>>>, std::_fl::vector<std::_fl::basic_string<char, std::_fl::char_traits<char>, std::_fl::allocator<char>>, std::_fl::allocator<std::_fl::basic_string<char, std::_fl::char_traits<char>, std::_fl::allocator<char>>>> const&) + 242 (dart_isolate.cc:903)
14  Flutter                                0x11f60044a flutter::DartIsolate::CreateRunningRootIsolate(flutter::Settings const&, fml::RefPtr<flutter::DartSnapshot const> const&, std::_fl::unique_ptr<flutter::PlatformConfiguration, std::_fl::default_delete<flutter::PlatformConfiguration>>, flutter::DartIsolate::Flags, 

...

16  Flutter                                0x11fb87462 flutter::Engine::Run(flutter::RunConfiguration) + 428 (engine.cc:241)

....

Thread 10:: io.flutter.1.raster
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1046377ac ???
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b70878 mach_msg2_internal + 84
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b69178 mach_msg_overwrite + 653
4   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b6237d mach_msg + 19
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1127d1863 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1127cbfeb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1127cb6ad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
8   Flutter                                0x11f5a3ead fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 65 (message_loop_darwin.mm:51)
9   Flutter                                0x11f59d6b2 fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 22 (message_loop_impl.cc:94)
10  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0::operator()() const + 122 (thread.cc:154) [inlined]
11  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 decltype(std::declval<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&>()()) std::_fl::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&>(fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&) + 122 (invoke.h:403) [inlined]
12  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 void std::_fl::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void, true>::__call<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&>(fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&) + 122 (invoke.h:488) [inlined]
13  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 std::_fl::__function::__alloc_func<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0, std::_fl::allocator<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()[abi:v15000]() + 122 (function.h:185) [inlined]
14  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 std::_fl::__function::__func<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0, std::_fl::allocator<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() + 135 (function.h:359)
15  Flutter                                0x11f5a2a33 std::_fl::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()[abi:v15000]() const + 15 (function.h:512) [inlined]
16  Flutter                                0x11f5a2a33 std::_fl::function<void ()>::operator()() const + 15 (function.h:1187) [inlined]
17  Flutter                                0x11f5a2a33 fml::ThreadHandle::ThreadHandle(std::_fl::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::operator()(void*) const + 19 (thread.cc:76) [inlined]
18  Flutter                                0x11f5a2a33 fml::ThreadHandle::ThreadHandle(std::_fl::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::__invoke(void*) + 27 (thread.cc:73)
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d218b _pthread_start + 99
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdae3 thread_start + 15

Thread 11:: io.flutter.1.io
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1046377ac ???
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b70878 mach_msg2_internal + 84
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b69178 mach_msg_overwrite + 653
4   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b6237d mach_msg + 19
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1127d1863 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 143
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1127cbfeb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1127cb6ad CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
8   Flutter                                0x11f5a3ead fml::MessageLoopDarwin::Run() + 65 (message_loop_darwin.mm:51)
9   Flutter                                0x11f59d6b2 fml::MessageLoopImpl::DoRun() + 22 (message_loop_impl.cc:94)
10  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0::operator()() const + 122 (thread.cc:154) [inlined]
11  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 decltype(std::declval<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&>()()) std::_fl::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&>(fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&) + 122 (invoke.h:403) [inlined]
12  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 void std::_fl::__invoke_void_return_wrapper<void, true>::__call<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&>(fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0&) + 122 (invoke.h:488) [inlined]
13  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 std::_fl::__function::__alloc_func<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0, std::_fl::allocator<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()[abi:v15000]() + 122 (function.h:185) [inlined]
14  Flutter                                0x11f5a2c91 std::_fl::__function::__func<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0, std::_fl::allocator<fml::Thread::Thread(std::_fl::function<void (fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)> const&, fml::Thread::ThreadConfig const&)::$_0>, void ()>::operator()() + 135 (function.h:359)
15  Flutter                                0x11f5a2a33 std::_fl::__function::__value_func<void ()>::operator()[abi:v15000]() const + 15 (function.h:512) [inlined]
16  Flutter                                0x11f5a2a33 std::_fl::function<void ()>::operator()() const + 15 (function.h:1187) [inlined]
17  Flutter                                0x11f5a2a33 fml::ThreadHandle::ThreadHandle(std::_fl::function<void ()>&&)::$_0::operator()(void*) const + 19 (thread.cc:76) [inlined]

...

8   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_fl::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>(fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0&&) + 145 (invoke.h:403) [inlined]
9   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 _ZNSt3_fl16__thread_executeB6v15000INS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS2_EEEEZN3fml21ConcurrentMessageLoopC1EmE3$_0JETpTnmJEEEvRNS_5tupleIJT_T0_DpT1_EEENS_15__tuple_indicesIJXspT2_EEEE + 145 (thread:284) [inlined]
10  Flutter                                0x11f59a751 void* std::_fl::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_fl::tuple<std::_fl::unique_ptr<std::_fl::__thread_struct, std::_fl::default_delete<std::_fl::__thread_struct>>, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>>(void*) + 191 (thread:295)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d218b _pthread_start + 99
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdae3 thread_start + 15

Thread 15:: io.worker.3
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1050c73bc ???
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d26f3 _pthread_cond_wait + 1211
3   Flutter                                0x11f57dbe0 std::_fl::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 5 (__threading_support:335) [inlined]
4   Flutter                                0x11f57dbe0 std::_fl::condition_variable::wait(std::_fl::unique_lock<std::_fl::mutex>&) + 18 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
5   Flutter                                0x11f599e2f void std::_fl::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_0>(std::_fl::unique_lock<std::_fl::mutex>&, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_0) + 50 (__mutex_base:398) [inlined]
6   Flutter                                0x11f599e2f fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 167 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:75)
7   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 145 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:20) [inlined]
8   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_fl::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>(fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0&&) + 145 (invoke.h:403) [inlined]
9   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 _ZNSt3_fl16__thread_executeB6v15000INS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS2_EEEEZN3fml21ConcurrentMessageLoopC1EmE3$_0JETpTnmJEEEvRNS_5tupleIJT_T0_DpT1_EEENS_15__tuple_indicesIJXspT2_EEEE + 145 (thread:284) [inlined]
10  Flutter                                0x11f59a751 void* std::_fl::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_fl::tuple<std::_fl::unique_ptr<std::_fl::__thread_struct, std::_fl::default_delete<std::_fl::__thread_struct>>, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>>(void*) + 191 (thread:295)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d218b _pthread_start + 99
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdae3 thread_start + 15

Thread 16:: io.worker.4
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1050c73bc ???
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d26f3 _pthread_cond_wait + 1211
3   Flutter                                0x11f57dbe0 std::_fl::__libcpp_condvar_wait[abi:v15000](_opaque_pthread_cond_t*, _opaque_pthread_mutex_t*) + 5 (__threading_support:335) [inlined]
4   Flutter                                0x11f57dbe0 std::_fl::condition_variable::wait(std::_fl::unique_lock<std::_fl::mutex>&) + 18 (condition_variable.cpp:46)
5   Flutter                                0x11f599e2f void std::_fl::condition_variable::wait<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_0>(std::_fl::unique_lock<std::_fl::mutex>&, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain()::$_0) + 50 (__mutex_base:398) [inlined]
6   Flutter                                0x11f599e2f fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::WorkerMain() + 167 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:75)
7   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0::operator()() const + 145 (concurrent_message_loop.cc:20) [inlined]
8   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 decltype(std::declval<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>()()) std::_fl::__invoke[abi:v15000]<fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>(fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0&&) + 145 (invoke.h:403) [inlined]
9   Flutter                                0x11f59a751 _ZNSt3_fl16__thread_executeB6v15000INS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS2_EEEEZN3fml21ConcurrentMessageLoopC1EmE3$_0JETpTnmJEEEvRNS_5tupleIJT_T0_DpT1_EEENS_15__tuple_indicesIJXspT2_EEEE + 145 (thread:284) [inlined]
10  Flutter                                0x11f59a751 void* std::_fl::__thread_proxy[abi:v15000]<std::_fl::tuple<std::_fl::unique_ptr<std::_fl::__thread_struct, std::_fl::default_delete<std::_fl::__thread_struct>>, fml::ConcurrentMessageLoop::ConcurrentMessageLoop(unsigned long)::$_0>>(void*) + 191 (thread:295)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d218b _pthread_start + 99
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdae3 thread_start + 15

Thread 17:: dart:io EventHandler
0   ???                                    0x104557a78 ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1050e9364 ???
2   Flutter                                0x11fb5d828 dart::bin::EventHandlerImplementation::EventHandlerEntry(unsigned long) + 312 (eventhandler_macos.cc:459)
3   Flutter                                0x11fb79923 dart::bin::ThreadStart(void*) + 83 (thread_macos.cc:91)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4d218b _pthread_start + 99
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x11c4cdae3 thread_start + 15

Thread 18:: Dart Profiler ThreadInterrupter
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd702dc ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x1046377ac ???
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x115b888ac thread_suspend + 84
3   Flutter                                0x11fd6bb42 dart::ThreadInterrupterMacOS::ThreadInterrupterMacOS(dart::OSThread*) + 19 (thread_interrupter_macos.cc:52) [inlined]
4   Flutter                                0x11fd6bb42 dart::ThreadInterrupterMacOS::ThreadInterrupterMacOS(dart::OSThread*) + 19 (thread_interrupter_macos.cc:48) [inlined]

...

Thread 23:: DartWorker
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd702dc ???
1   <translation info unavailable>         0x10547db50 ???
2   ???                                    0x16514c5d6 ???
3   ???                                    0x16514505d ???
4   ???                                    0x165144733 ???
5   ???                                    0x16510f8cb ???
6   ???                                    0x165128a79 ???
7   ???                                    0x165125350 ???
8   ???                                    0x165124f9d ???
9   ???                                    0x165124c88 ???
10  ???                                    0x165123e15 ???
11  ???                                    0x16512297a ???
12  ???                                    0x16512ada8 ???
13  ???                                    0x16428920e ???
14  ???                                    0x165128a79 ???
15  ???                                    0x165125350 ???
16  ???                                    0x165124f9d ???
17  ???                                    0x165124c88 ???
18  ???                                    0x165123e15 ???
19  ???                                    0x16512297a ???
20  ???                                    0x16512ada8 ???
21  ???                                    0x16428920e ???
      
 ...

Thread 4 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000115ad13c0  rsi: 0x000000030cdf8000  rbp: 0x000000030cdf7d10  rsp: 0x000000030cdf7ab0
   r8: 0x000000030cdf7c28   r9: 0x000000030cdf7d10  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x000000011c4fe4f1
  r12: 0x0000000000002603  r13: 0x0000003000000008  r14: 0x000000030cdf8000  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: <unavailable>       rfl: 0x0000000000000287
 tmp0: 0xffffffffffffffff tmp1: 0x0000000104557a4c tmp2: 0x0000000171f95520


Binary Images:
       0x20490f000 -        0x20499ffff dyld (*) <18f658dd-20f3-324d-b7ac-8a9c60b574b3> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x165440000 -        0x16545cfff libCGInterfaces.dylib (*) <240695a2-427d-3277-97de-96fea7266ed1> /Volumes/VOLUME/*/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Libraries/libCGInterfaces.dylib

...
    

